# What does status=finished mean in Google Chrome developer tools network tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-status-codes, developer-tools

I was trying to put the Twitter widget onto a few Blogger/Blogspot blogs (which is supposed to be super-simple and almost was) when I noticed it wasn't working sometimes -- specifically the times when I wasn't logged in to Blogger/Google as an author of that blog. The Chrome developer tools show a status simply as "Finished" without any HTTP response code (e.g. 200, 404) included for apis.google.com/js/plusone.js and platform.twitter.com/widgets.js whereas Firefox Firebug shows HTTP 200 for plusone.js and doesn't even list widgets.js in its network tab. I can see this "Finished" on any blogspot blog, even http://buzz.blogger.com/ (though only for the Twitters widgets.js; plusone.js loads correctly with a 304).

What is going on here? Is it because these are Javascript files? Is Chrome trying to skip making the call when it suspects/expects a 304 Not Modified response, but then doesn't actually load the previous response contents?

Comment: Can you share some network capture ? "Save as HAR" in network panel or use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)